# Eclipse spontaneously can't import ActionBarSherlock after being properly set up a long time ago

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am working on an app that uses both ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu. It works great and I am about ready to release it when all of a sudden eclipse spontaneously decided that it can't find com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

This is what the SlidingActivity extends SherlockActivity looks like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/VzTy42R.png]

Similarly my app itself is riddled with errors.

It was working fine and I don't know of anything that would have changed. It is in my Dropbox so maybe somehow that did something. It seems to still be able to find the referenced ABS project. I have tried removing the reference and it from the build path and adding it again, adding ABS as an external JAR, refreshing the project, restarting eclipse...basically everything that isn't really doing anything.
Here are pictures of the references and build path if that helps:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/42uBn.jpg

Thanks for anything you can point me towards!

Comment: use your old ShareLockLib in your Project(if you have backup). use that in your Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the external jar on your own, try:
1) right-click your actionBarSherlock library project, go to properties, click "Android", go to bottom, check "is library".
2) right-click your main project->properties->Android, at the bottom (uncheck "is library") click "add" and choose your previously added library.

You should also remove any wrong jars from build path and rebuild your project. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked fore me. Thanks! However now on export I am getting the Dalvik conversion error so many people talk about. In the android dependencies it lists ABS.jar twice in the same location. Could that be the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your android sdk to some other folder and change your sdk path in eclipse to newly copied sdk path.
to change path of you sdk in eclipse

```
eclipse->windows->prefernces->android     //here you will see the path set earlier
```

if you cant find the project in explorer after changing the path,import them.
then clean your project.

this worked for me,hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed the latest **Android Build System** and then **Check for updates**. After that, re-start Eclipse and it should build fine.